# All indexes of List

Tags: c#, arrays, list

I want all the indexes of List data type in C# into any integer array. Is that possible?
I tried this:

```
ckey = Command.IndexOf("Callers:");
```

where `ckey` is an `int[]` and `Command` is `List<String>`.

Comment: If you want _all_ indexes, what is the meaning of `"Callers:"`? Or do you only want indexes of `"Callers:"`?

Comment: My apology, yes you are absolutely right. I need all indexes of string Callers:

Comment: @Aemz `I need all indexes of string Callers:` if so how does your *accepted answer* give this?

Comment: @14V Because this is also fulfill my project requirement. Helps me a lot.Also what I asked, This is best answer accordingly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
int[] indices = Enumerable.Range(0, Command.Count).ToArray();
```

EDIT: If you want to find the indices of a given string you can do:

```
string toFind = //
int[] indices = strs.Select((s, idx) => new { Str = s, Idx = idx })
                    .Where(p => p.Str == toFind)
                    .Select(p => p.Idx)
                    .ToArray();
```

Comment: Thanks you so much, this is working for me, but I need to know if I want to have all the indexes of any string present in list, what should I use to do?
That is I want to have all indexes of "Callers:" string into integer array from List Command.